# What is the geometrical meaning of symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, euclidean-geometry, symmetric-matrices

Could anyone help explain what is the geometric meaning of symmetric matrix in context of hypercube or parallelepiped  in Euclidean coordinate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most obvious geometric interpretation of a symmetric matrix stems from its eigenvectors - they are orthogonal to each other so from them you can construct hypercube with sides for example of unit length. Matrix of eigenvectors  allows you to  diagonalize the matrix.

Additionally I quote wikipedia.
"More explicitly: For every symmetric real matrix $A$ there exists a real orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $D = Q^TAQ$ is a diagonal matrix. Every symmetric matrix is thus, up to choice of an orthonormal basis, a diagonal matrix."

So in some orthogonal coordinate system this matrix is represented by diagonal matrix which itself is made from column vectors which are orthogonal to each other and form rectangular cuboid whose volume is equal to the absolute value of determinant for this symmetric matrix. Of course it has non zero value only for full rank matrices.